# Information on the Exploitation and Automatability Data for Vulnerable components

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, cvss

Is there any tool providing information such as exploitability state (i.e., None, POC & Functional/Active) and automatability data for a specified vulnerable component name and version?

Comment: You mean, besides CVSS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.